# json_encode and question marks

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get some data from MySQL database in utf-8, but i can't resolve a problem with encoding. I've googled about this problem and tried to fix it in different ways, but i still can't get normal text wit cyrillic symbols.

So here my code

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$database="******";
$username="******";
$password="******";

$sql= "select dle_post.id,dle_post.title,dle_post.short_story,dle_post.full_story,dle_post.xfields,dle_post.category from dle_post order by dle_post.id limit 500, 550;";

$con =mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response= array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"title"=>$row[1],"short_story"=>$row[2],"full_story"=>$row[3],"xfields"=>$row[4],"category"=>$row[5]));

}

$json = json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo $json;
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

I've tried:

1. JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
2. header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
3. AddDefaultCharset utf8 in htaccess

and some other approaches from google and stackoverflow, BUT i always get this question marks. Example of output:

```
{
        "id": "10235",
        "title": "??????? ???????",
        "short_story": "???? ?????? ?? ????????. ??? ????, ??????????, ?????, ???????? ??????? ? ???????. ?? ?????????? ? ?????????? ???????? ????? ??????? ???????, ??? ????????? ?????????? ?? ???? ??????. ? ???? ???? ??????????, ?????? ??????? ? ???????? ???????? ????????? ??????????.",
        "full_story": "<br /><b>????????:</b> ??????? ???????<br /><b>???:</b> 2013<br /><b>??????:</b> ??????<br /><b>????????:</b> ??????? ???????<br /><b>????:</b> ?????????<br /><br /><b>? ?????:</b> ????? ??????, ??????? ??????????, ???????? ????????, ????????? ??????<br /><br /><b>???????? (??):</b> 19 ???????? 2015<br /><br /><b>???????? ???????????????? ????????? (??):</b> 19 ??? 2015, ??<br /><br /><b>???????:</b> ????????, ????????? 12 ???<br /><br /><b>????????:</b> ???? ?????? ?? ????????. ??? ????, ??????????, ?????, ???????? ??????? ? ???????. ?? ?????????? ? ?????????? ???????? ????? ??????? ???????, ??? ????????? ?????????? ?? ???? ??????. ? ???? ???? ??????????, ?????? ??????? ? ???????? ???????? ????????? ??????????.",
        "category": "32"
    },
```

In similar cases people at least get something like **\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432**

I don't know php, just learning Java, so this situation is quite confusing.

Comment: are getting it ok from the db? What does `$row[1]` give you? Or a `var_dump($response)`?

Comment: It gives me the same question marks

Comment: But now with new black ones �??? � ???? ? ?????? ?????????�

Comment: Did you set up your database as utf-8?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php with the appropriate charset. Are you tables setup to use utf-8 as well?

Comment: @DennisKoch I didn't set up the database, its already running. But it works in UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) in order to information from phpmyadmin

Comment: @SanderBackus Yes, Tables use utf8_general_ci

Comment: So set your connection charset to utf8_general_ci too.